# How to populate city dropdown by selecting value in country dropdown from the mysql database in codeiginiter

Tags: php

I have tried a lot to find the solution of how to populate the city dropdown by selecting the country in the first dropdown but i didn't understand the available solutions.I have populated the first dropdown from the database but i cant populate the second one due to the no knowledge of Ajax. Please provide the full code of ajax or jquery how to populate the second one by selecting the first Thanks.

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-md-4 control-label">City</label>
    <div class="col-md-8 text center">
        <select class="form-control" name="city" id="city">
        <?php foreach($cityData as $data){

                    $id = $data->city_id;
                    $country_name =$data->city_name;
                ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $city_name; ?></option>

            <?php } ?>
        </select>   

    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-md-4 control-label">Country</label>
    <div class="col-md-8 text center">
        <select class="form-control" class="country" name="country">
            <option value="">Select Country</option>
            <?php foreach($countryData as $data){

                    $id = $data->country_id;
                    $country_name =$data->country_name;
                ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $country_name; ?></option>

                <?php } ?>
        </select>                                           
    </div>
</div>
```

**Ajax Code**

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.country").change(function(){
        var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../form_controller/populate_cities",
            data: { country : selectedCountry } 
        });.done(function(data){
            $("#city").html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Controller to Populate Cities**

```
public function populate_cities(){
    $this->load->model('cities');

    $country_id = $this->input->post('country');


    $data['cityData'] = $this->cities->getData($country_id);
    $this->load->view('reservation_detail');

}
```

Comment: Show us what you tried. Please format your post.

Comment: Hi @Bilal. Thank You For Asking Question. But, Please Provide Your Code Which You Tried From Your End. And, What is This "*..Please provide the full code of ajax or jquery*" ?? **Stack Overflow Is Not A Coaching Centre At All**

Comment: Ok i will provide but i am new to the stackoverflow that was the reason and this was my first question which i was asking

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:I Assume you have country and city and state table**

**How this code working:-** When page load, at that time controller index function is called and trigger a model function getCountry() and  this function retrieve all the available country name and pass this to view. When country drop down value change it called a ajax function selectState(current country id) and this ajax function called a controller loadData() and this function called a model function loadData(filter type like state or city) and on that basic this model function return data. The same procedure follow for state drown change but with different java script function selectCity(state id) function and follow previous flow. Both the java script function call loadData js function for loading the data.

**Java Script Code:-**

```
function selectState(country_id){
  if(country_id!="-1"){
    loadData('state',country_id);
    $("#city_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select city</option>");
  }else{
    $("#state_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select state</option>");
    $("#city_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select city</option>");
  }
}

function selectCity(state_id){
  if(state_id!="-1"){
   loadData('city',state_id);
  }else{
   $("#city_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select city</option>");
  }
}

function loadData(loadType,loadId){
  var dataString = 'loadType='+ loadType +'&loadId='+ loadId;
  $("#"+loadType+"_loader").show();
  $("#"+loadType+"_loader").fadeIn(400).html('Please wait... <img src="image/loading.gif" />');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "loadData",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
      $("#"+loadType+"_loader").hide();
      $("#"+loadType+"_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select "+loadType+"</option>");
      $("#"+loadType+"_dropdown").append(result);
    }
 });
}
```

**Controller Functions:-**

```
public function index()
{
   $this->load->model('model');
   $result['list']=$this->model->getCountry();
   $this->load->view('top');
   $this->load->view('index',$result);
   $this->load->view('footer');
}

 public function loadData()
 {
   $loadType=$_POST['loadType'];
   $loadId=$_POST['loadId'];

   $this->load->model('model');
   $result=$this->model->getData($loadType,$loadId);
   $HTML="";

   if($result->num_rows() > 0){
     foreach($result->result() as $list){
       $HTML.="<option value='".$list->id."'>".$list->name."</option>";
     }
   }
   echo $HTML;
 }
```

**Model Functions:-**

```
function getCountry()
{
   $this->db->select('id,country_name');
   $this->db->from('country');
   $this->db->order_by('country_name', 'asc');
   $query=$this->db->get();
   return $query;
}

function getData($loadType,$loadId)
{
   if($loadType=="state"){
    $fieldList='id,state_name as name';
    $table='state';
    $fieldName='country_id';
    $orderByField='state_name';
   }else{
    $fieldList='id,city_name as name';
    $table='city';
    $fieldName='state_id';
    $orderByField='city_name';
   }
   $this->db->select($fieldList);
   $this->db->from($table);
   $this->db->where($fieldName, $loadId);
   $this->db->order_by($orderByField, 'asc');
   $query=$this->db->get();
   return $query;
 }
```